# SOCKS proxy forwarding

Tags: ssh, socks

Here is the configuration I have:
3 PCs : PC-1, PC-2, PC-3

Here is what I did initially:
Set up a SOCKS proxy on PC-1 forwarded to PC-2 using ssh:

```
PC-1$ ssh -ND 1080 PC-2
```

I configured the browser to use 127.0.0.1:1080 and everything works. Now I want to forward all the connections to PC-3 via PC-2. So, something like:

```
PC-1$ ssh -ND 1080 PC-2
PC-2$ ssh -ND 1080 PC-3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the SOCKS proxy on PC-2 and forward the port to PC-1 as follows:

```
PC-2$ ssh -ND 1080 PC-3
PC-1$ ssh -NL 1080:localhost:1080 PC-2
```

Configure the browser on PC-1 to use `127.0.0.1:1080`.

Answer (score 1):

With a more modern variant in only one command:

```
PC-1$ ssh -J PC-2 -ND 1080 PC-3
```